# Is the orthogonal complement just the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

so I am trying to self study linear algebra and dear god that this has got to be the hardest branch of math I have encountered, and yes I love calculus. Right now, I am  taking up orthogonals and its related subtopics. One thing I can't verify  right now is if the orthogonal complement is just the basis of the subspace. For example if I was asked to find the orthogonal complement of the subspace $W$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$ where $W$:

$W= \{ [a-b-c, a, b+c]: a,b,c ∈ \mathbb{R} \}$

$= \{a[1,1,0]+b[-1,0,1]+c[-1,0,1]\}$

with this I could say that the orthogonal complement of $W$ is

$\{[1,1,0],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]\}$

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?  Please do correct me if there are any inconsistencies. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As you can see, W is spanned by 2 vectors (which are linearly independent of each other). The orthogonal complement of W in $R^4$ is the space of vectors orthogonal to everything in W. It will be 2 dimensional and so spanned by 2 vectors orthogonal to those in W. So, find 2 vectors orthogonal to those two and you are pretty much done.

Comment: @Paul Hi, I would just like to know how you determined immediately that W is spanned by 2 vectors.

Comment: There are only two different vectors making up combinations in W. The multiple of c is redundant since b can be any real number.

Answer (score 1):

The orthogonal complement of $W$ is the set$$W^\perp=\{v\in\Bbb R^4\mid(\forall w\in W):v.w=0\}.$$It follows from this that $W^\perp$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$, and therefore it cannot possibly consist only of those three vectors. And, actually, *none* of them belong to $W^\perp$.

Comment: Ohhh so from there I could proceed to Ax=0 then correct me if am wrong but with that I could say that the nullspace of A is the orthogonal complement of w right?

Comment: What is $A$? There is no $A$ in your question?

Comment: oh Sorry I meant $w$

Comment: Since $W$ is spanned by $(1,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$, the space $W^\perp$ can be computed as the set of solutions of the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}(x,y,z).(1,1,0)=0\\(x,y,z).(-1,0,1)=0\end{array}\right.\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y=0\\-x+z=0.\end{array}\right.$$